# The Resource Cannot be Found with a class model tagged with [HttpPost] in MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm new in MVC5. I have a controller named as "list" for listing books and another controller named as "new"  for creating a new record. I tagged the "new" with [HttpPost]. But when I run the application, it gives the "The resource cannot be found -  Requested Url:/boks/new/" error.

**-Controllers**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using BookStore.Data;
using BookStore.Models;

namespace BookStore.Controllers
{
    public class BookController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Book
      public  ActionResult List()
        {
            return View(BookData.Books);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult New(Book newBook) 
        {
            BookData.Books.Add(newBook);
            return RedirectToAction("List");

        }
    }
}
```

**-Model**

```
namespace BookStore.Models
{
    public class Book
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public int PublishYear { get; set; }
        public decimal price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

-**List View**

```
@model IEnumerable<BookStore.Models.Book>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List";
}

<h2>List</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Author)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PublishYear)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.price)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Author)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PublishYear)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.price)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

**-New View**

```
model BookStore.Models.Book

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "New";
}

<h2>New</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Book</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Author, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Author, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Author, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PublishYear, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PublishYear, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PublishYear, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.price, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.price, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.price, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

**-BookData**

```
**using System.Collections.Generic;
using BookStore.Models;

namespace BookStore.Data
{
    public class BookData
    {
        public static List<Book> Books = new List<Book>
        {
            new Book
            {
                Id=1,
                Title="Test1",
                Author="John Doe",
                PublishYear=2015,
                price=10
            },

            new Book
            {
                Id=2,
                Title="Test2",
                Author="Jane Doe",
                PublishYear=2014,
                price=15
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I have read the similar articles but ı can't able to find a solution so far.

Comment: You don't have `list` and `new` controller - you have `book` controller with `list` action and `new` action. Because you have `book` controller, your url should be: `/book/new`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to browse "/Book/New" you don't need [Post]

It's better to create an action for get operation and another action for post operation.

The action for get operation will use when you browse that address, the action for post operation will use when submitting the form.

Also in your list view you should use a link to your new action:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "New")
```

As an example:

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual ActionResult New()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult New(Book entity)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Save book
            return RedirectToAction("List");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message);
    }
    return View(entity);            
}
```

Comment: Without post or with get it adds a empty record on list because of RedirectToAction.